# Duplicate resources [style-ldltr-v21/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined]

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

when i create empty android project in Android Studio or intel idea 
I get same errors

```
Error:Error: Duplicate resources
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
[style-ldltr-v21/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined]
MyApplication244/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/25.1.1/res/values-ldltr-v21/values-ldltr-v21.xml
[style-ldltr-v21/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined]
MyApplication244/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/25.1.1/res/values-ldltr-v21/values-ldltr-v21.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

my build.gradle(app) file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.inoob.myapplication244"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
}
```

build.gradle(MyApplication244)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried change api version. 21,22,23
But i have same problem.
Please describe me what it mean . I newcomer in android.

Comment: Try to remove the line: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'`. You do not need it with the `design` library after it

Comment: @cricket_007 , thanks! I tried, It not fix my problem(( i also removed  `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` `androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })` `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`